# Can I execute a remote placed .vbs file using wscript command?

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, wsh

I have tried using the wscript command with local file share and it works perfectly.

Ex: `wscript \\192.168.10.1\script\hello.vbs`

Is there any way I can run the file from remote HTTP server?

Something like: `wscript http://192.168.10.1/script/hello.vbs`

TIA

Comment: Update: Achieved this by combining 2 commands together:

`bitsadmin /transfer myDownloads /download /priority normal http://192.168.10.1/test.vbs C:\DATA\test.vbs & wscript "C:\DATA\test.vbs"`
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

wscript.exe does not support calling VBScripts directly from an URL. Why not use the FTP server?

Why do you want to use the HTTP?
An solution for you could be, if you have it hosted on an NAS, try to open ports so that you can access it from your IP adres.

I could help you with it if you need it, but you need to give some more details about the hardware (NAS/Router)

Comment: Not entirely true if you own the server you can remove restrictions to downloading `vbs` then once downloaded it could be executed.

Comment: It's not quite the same, you have to download it first. I think the poster just wants a direct approach to it's VB script.

Comment: Agreed but *"You cannot run a VB script from HTTP"* is bit misleading I'd suggest something more like *"`wscript.exe` does not support calling VBScripts directly from an URL"*.

Comment: Agree with you @Jaxhead. But, my problem here is more towards executing this remote script from command prompt with a single command. NAS is still an option but considering that I do not have sufficient infrastructure to setup one, do you see any other workaround?

Comment: I do not exactly know what you are trying, but mayby this is an solution for you:

Download/install Dropbox
use "net use" to create a driveletter for your dropbox, assign your cmd script to this.
Now you will have the vbscript online and you can directly access it from your computer.

Comment: Let me be more clear about the problem statement, I want to have a single line command to execute the a vbs file which is accessible publicly on external network (Ex:http) and I want to do this with in-built commands in windows.